# Exporting data from expect script

Tags: bash, automation, telnet, expect

so i've written a short expect script which logs into a APC Power Distribution Unit interface via telnet and polls the current ampage.

```
    #!/usr/bin/expect
    set ip "192.168.0.1"
    set username "myusername"
    set password "mypassword"
    spawn "/bin/bash"
    send "telnet $ip\r"
    expect "*User Name*"
    send "$username\r"
    expect "*Password*"
    send "$password\r"
    expect "*APC*"
    send -- "phReading all current\r"
    expect "*Success*"
    send  "quit\r"
    expect eof
```

The script does its job and I see the amps on screen, displayed like this:

```
    apc>phReading all current
    E000: Success
    1: 7.5 A
    apc>quit
```

What i need to do is 'export' that 7.5 figure, either to a text file or pass it to a bash script as a variable.

Any ideas on how i can do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Expect is an extension of TCL, so you have access to all of TCL's constructs.

If I were you I would have the expect script write directly to a file.

See the section "Writing a file" here: http://wiki.tcl.tk/367. It has a simple example for just that. In your case, you will want to open the file for append (a) instead of write (w).

open command documentation at: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/open.htm

Let me know how that works for you.

Comment: Thanks James!
I have added set filename, set fileId and close commands to my script in the relevant places. The output file is created but remains empty.

I can see i need to use 'puts' to put the text into the file, but i'm not sure how to tell it that I want the output of this command - send "phReading all current\r" - to the file. Any ideas? :)

Comment: After you send the command you need to expect some result. Use the -re switch and set a regexp for what you want to match. Then, assuming you do get a match, you will be able to use 'puts' with the correct file id and the $expect_out (0,string) variable, which will hold the portion of the output matched by your expect -re statement. You may also want to put 'exp_internal 1' somewhere near the beginning of the script to obtain valuable diagnostics on expect's matching operations.